# Generate a clickable URI that contains starting url + document.title + another string

Tags: javascript, html, url

I would like to generate a clickable URL that contains a starting URL string + `document.title` + another string + `response.text`. The link text should be "click here"

**This is my code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    'use strict';
    var res = "";
    (async () => {
      let response = await fetch('https://httpbin.org/encoding/utf8');

      let text = await response.text(); // read response body as text

      document.getElementById("KK1").innerHTML = (text.slice(0, 10));

      // I want to generate a clickable uri that contains starting url+document.title+another string+response.text. The link text should be "click here"
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<a href="https://www.google.com/search?"+ document.title+ "ANOTHER-STRING-HERE"+  text">Click Here</a>';
    })()

  </script>
  <title>My File Dowmloder.rar</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>My First Web Page</h2>
  <p>My First Paragraph.</p> Generate clickable URL from parameters. <a id="demo"></a><br>
  <p id="KK1"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

When I run this code the URL generated only contains the starting URL string, i.e. "https://www.google.com/search?". But I want the full URL to contain starting URL + `document.title` + another string + `response.text`.

**Starting URL:** https://www.google.com/search?
**document.title:** The page title
**Another string:** Any string
**response.text:** The string received from fetch

Looking forward for your help. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do but this gets stuff and makes a link.

```js
fetch('https://httpbin.org/encoding/utf8')
  .then((response) => {
    return response.text();
  })
  .then((text) => {
    document.getElementById("KK1").innerHTML = text.slice(0, 10);
    document.getElementById("demo").href = `https://www.google.com/search?${document.title}another string${text}`;
  });
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>My File Dowmloder.rar</title>
</head>

<body>

  <h2>My First Web Page</h2>
  <p>My First Paragraph.</p>

  Generate clickable URL from parameters.

  <a id="demo">Click Here</a><br>

  <p id="KK1"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks a million @Will